# C++ class function fails to change variables

Tags: c++, class

When calling buildingname.damagebuilding(34) the currenthealth would only decrease temporarily, the first print prints 100 the second prints 66 but after calling damagebuilding again it's reset to 100 again. currenthealth isn't set anywhere else but in the constructor.

Class:

```
class building {
public:
    int maxhealth;
    int currenthealth;
    int cost;
    int level;
    int Posx;
    int Posy;
    building() {}
    building(int h, int c, int x, int y) {
        maxhealth = h;
        currenthealth = h;
        cost = c;
        level = 1;
        Posx = x;
        Posy = y;
    }

    void damageBuilding(int h) {
        if (currenthealth - h > 0) {
            std::cout << " Before "+std::to_string(currenthealth);
            currenthealth=currenthealth-h;
            std::cout << "\n After " + std::to_string(currenthealth)+"\n";
        }
        else { 
            std::cout << "\n Building destroyed "; 
        } 
    }

};
```

Where it's called:

```
void fire(int x,int y) {
    if (activeplayer == 1 && bulletsP1 > 0 && sgrid2[x][y] != 0) {
        if (sgrid2[x][y] > 0 && sgrid2[x][y] < 9) {
            for (std::list<cannon>::iterator it = cannonsP1.begin(); it != cannonsP1.end(); ++it) {
                if (it->ID == bulletsP1) { 
                    findbuilding(x, y).damageBuilding(it->damage); 
                }
            }
        }
        bulletsP1--;
        sgrid2[x][y] = grid2[x][y];
        vgrid2[x][y] = 3;
    }
}
```

Findbuilding:

```
building &  findbuilding(int x, int y) {
    if (activeplayer == 1) {

        for each (building b in bgrid2)
        {
            if (b.Posx == x && b.Posy == y) {
                return b;
            }
        }

    }
    //else if (activeplayer == 2) {
    else {
        for each (building b in bgrid)
        {
            if (b.Posx == x && b.Posy == y) {
                return b;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Off Topic] your use of `to_string` in `std::cout << " Before "+std::to_string(currenthealth);` is not needed and is costly.  You can just use `std::cout << " Before " << currenthealth;` and now you have no dynamic memory allocation or extra copying.

Comment: What does `findbuilding(x, y)` return? Hopefully it is a reference.

Comment: @drescherjm A building on the location x,y

Comment: @BrianBoddaert But how? Can you post the signature of that method?

Comment: Is it a reference to a building? If not you are likely changing a copy of a building..

Comment: @drescherjm building findbuilding(int x, int y) {
 if (activeplayer == 1) {

  for each (building b in bgrid2)
  {
   if (b.Posx == x && b.Posy == y) {
    return b;
   }
  }
       }
 }

Comment: There is your bug.. You are returning a copy. It should be `building& findbuilding(int x, int y)` instead.

Comment: So how do I do it instead? @drescherjm

Comment: I gave you the answer. change `building findbuilding(int x, int y)` to `building& findbuilding(int x, int y)`

Comment: If that does not work with your container return a pointer to the building and update the code that calls this to use the returned building*.

Comment: @drescherjm after changing it to that the mistake remained and it kept saying the currenthealth is now 249 instead of 100, no clue why

Comment: You will probably have to use your debugger.

Comment: You can see that value is modified, so problem you had is solved now you have to step your code in debugger as @drescherjm mentioned and find what is passed to `damageBuilding` function :-)

Comment: There could still be a bug in findbuilding() depending on the implementation. Please edit your question and add the exact code for this function. Your pseudo code you posted as a comment makes me believe you still have a copy and you are now returning a reference to that (which still will not work and will be undefined behavior).

Comment: @BrianBoddaert -- Did your compiler warn you that your `findbuilding()` function potentially doesn't return a value?  If that function fails to return a value, your program is in the world of *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I believe `for each (building b in bgrid2)` makes a copy as well. Although I don't recognize this syntax.

Comment: Also `for each (building b in bgrid2)` -- that isn't C++.

Comment: @BrianBoddaert -- The program still has a huge bug if `b.Posx == x && b.Posy == y` is false for that entire loop.  As a matter of fact, getting weird results being returned can be caused by just that -- not returning anything from a function that is supposed to return something (whether it was a reference as now, or an object in your original code).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie how come? It seems to work just fine

Comment: @BrianBoddaert -- Undefined behavior.  Your function is supposed to return a reference to `building`.  So what will you be returning if that condition is `false`?  That's why you should read your compiler warnings carefully -- it didn't warn you just for a joke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function

```
findbuilding(x, y)
```

returns instance of class `building` by value, it means you are modifying just the copy of an instance. You have to return `pointer` (*) or `reference` (&) to that instance, to get effect.

---

```
building findbuilding(int x, int y) {}
```

to

```
building & findbuilding(int x, int y) {}
```

---

There is your instance `i` with `currenthealth = 100` in memory

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |  i  |     |     |
|     |     | 100 |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

if you return it by value `copy`, this cell is copied to another place in memory, `iCpy`

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
|     |     |  i  |     | iCpy |
|     |     | 100 |     |  66  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
               ^           ^
               |           --------------- You are modifying this copy
               --------------------------- The real instance stays unchanged
```

By passing an reference to this instance

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |  i  |     |     |
|     |     |  66 |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
               ^           
               -------------------------- You are modifying real instance
```

Comment: Thank you, It however didn't fix it and made things a lot more confusing to me, it for instance changed currenthealth to a seemingly random number each time I run it again

Comment: As i mentioned in comments, your problem was _method fails to change variables_, now you can see that member variable is modified succesfully in method, problem is just in function `damageBuilding`. Debug it step by step and you will see whats the problem. Not that tough. :-)

Comment: Ok! I'll try just that, reading all the responses got me the feeling there's a lot more wrong with my code than I thought. Thanks for the help still!

Comment: @BrianBoddaert My advice is to learn how to single step through your code with a debugger looking at your variables at each step to help determine where your code deviates from what you expect it to do. I do this often and I have been a programmer since the 1980s.